# DownloadManager takes 3-5 minutes to stop a download, only when SD Card is used

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-download-manager, download-manager

I'm starting a 2Gb file download using the DownloadManager, and in doing so I offer the user the option to pick where they want to save that file: internal storage or SD card. 
Also, I give the user an option to cancel said download. Here is my code:

```
DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
query.setFilterById(downloadId);
Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(query);

try { 
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int status =cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
        if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING || 
                status == DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING) {
            downloadManager.remove(downloadId);
        } 
    } 
} finally { 
    cursor.close();
}
```

**My problem:** when downloading to internal storage, the **.remove(downloadId)** call works instantly, and the download stops. But when downloading to the SD Card (on a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge), using the same code, it takes 3-5 minutes to stop the download.

Any ideas on removing that delay?

**Edit**: some paths examples, returned by Activity.getExternalFilesDirs():

> /storage/emulated/.../ - this is internal
>
> /storage/0123-4567/.../ - this is the SD Card

Comment: Can you give examples of paths you consider to be on internal storage and on SD card?

Comment: just edited the question to add the paths

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/...... is called external storage. Obtained with getExternalStorageDirectory(). But i do not see a solution. sorry. Did you test other devices?

Comment: both are called "external storage", but the first one is actually internal. Hence the "emulated" in the path. I have tested with other devices - same behavior

Comment: You can reach internal storage with getFilesDir();

Comment: `it takes 3-5 minutes`. And how much would a complete download take? You took a 2GB file. But say you take a much smaller one?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for myself: it looks like before the download starts, the DownloadManager creates a 2Gb file (the size of the file I'm downloading) filled with zeros so that it keeps the storage allocated. That file-write operation is what's making this slow on a SD Card.

The internal storage on the S7 Edge is crazy-fast, which is why the problem is not present there. The actual problem (an OS bug in my opinion) is that calling **.remove()** waits for that initial write operation instead of cancelling it.